# Using Excel VBA to screen-scrape internet - cannot reference second page

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

my question is relatively simple and maddeningly evasive. It's not unlike many questions I've found on the internet and at StackOverflow yet no suggestions have helped my little conundrum....

Using Excel2010 I wasnt to enter data into a single field, submit it (Part1) and capture a few lines of data (part2) , paste into excel in a list/table format (part30 - and do it 999,999 times.....Part 1 and 3 are working - Part2 refuses to acknowledge the new internet window and all gettagnames and SelectTable workarounds just use the original URL - the attached was a desperate attempt using Sendkeys - which worse perfectly! - for the first loop - then absolutely nothing!

anyway, the code should be fairly simple - appologies for some mess in the coding order - it's down to me starting to cut out bits with a scalple but after hours of messing about resorted to hatchets...

```
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
Dim ie As InternetExplorer

Sub EPF_FSA()

'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim iHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String
Dim miss1 As Integer
Dim FrmNo As Long
Dim FrmName As String
Dim Address1 As String
Dim Address2 As String
Dim Address3 As String
Dim Address4 As String
Dim Address5 As String
Dim Address6 As String
Dim Address7 As String
Dim Address8 As String
Dim AnyLuck As String
Dim RowNum As Integer
Dim ColNum As Integer

RowNum = 1
ColNum = 1


FrmNo = 100111

While FrmNo <= 100112
'Do While FrmNo <= 100112
On Error GoTo Err_Clear
sURL = "http://www.fsa.gov.uk/register/epfSearchForm.do"


Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
'Set Ex = CreateObject("MicrosoftExcel.application")
ie.navigate sURL
ie.Visible = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLdoc = ie.document

HTMLdoc.all.epfref.Value = FrmNo

For Each iHTML_Element In HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("input")

If iHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then miss1 = miss1 + 1
If miss1 = 2 Then iHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then Err.Clear
Resume Next
'PART 2 ********************************************************************
Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Call SendKeys("^a")
DoEvents
Call SendKeys("^c")
DoEvents

      ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
        range("A2").Select

'Copy and select relevant text to sheet 2

  Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
 FrmName = Cells(39, "A").Value

 Address1 = Cells(59, "A").Value
 Address2 = Cells(60, "A").Value
 Address3 = Cells(61, "A").Value
 Address4 = Cells(62, "A").Value
 Address5 = Cells(63, "A").Value
 Address6 = Cells(64, "A").Value
 Address7 = Cells(65, "A").Value
 Address8 = Cells(66, "A").Value
 AnyLuck = Cells(47, "A").Value


  Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
 Cells(RowNum, "A").Value = FrmNo
 Cells(RowNum, "B").Value = FrmName
 Cells(RowNum, "C").Value = Address1
 Cells(RowNum, "D").Value = Address2
 Cells(RowNum, "E").Value = Address3
 Cells(RowNum, "F").Value = Address4
 Cells(RowNum, "G").Value = Address5
 Cells(RowNum, "H").Value = Address6
 Cells(RowNum, "I").Value = Address7
 Cells(RowNum, "J").Value = Address8
 Cells(RowNum, "K").Value = AnyLuck
   RowNum = RowNum + 1
'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    range("A2").Select
'MsgBox (FrmNo & Chr(10) & FrmName)
'Part 3
FrmNo = FrmNo + 1
ie.Quit
ie.Quit
Wend
'Loop

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can go directly to the results page. Try:

```
sUrl = "http://www.fsa.gov.uk/register/epfRefSearch.do?epfRef="
sUrl = sUrl & frmNo
```

and then just navigate to that page. The actual details are then in a div with an ID of "box"